# Spotfire Text to Integer for Dates

Tags: date, datetime, text, integer, spotfire

I am attempting to load time series data from an excel spreadsheet into spotfire. In my spreadsheet there is a separate column for year (spotfire sees it as an integer) and month (spotfire sees it as text) since it is in the three letter abbreviation format ie January is JAN. I am trying to avoid changing the data in excel and would like to do all of my work in spotfire as this will be updated periodically. How do I link these columns in spotfire so that I can plot a variable over a time frame?

Comment: @geop- Why not concatenate both the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Insert > Insert Calculated Column... Make sure you have the right data table selected. In the Expression field type:

```
Date([year],
   case  when [month]="JAN" then 1
      when [month]="FEB" then 2
      when [month]="MAR" then 3
      when [month]="APR" then 4
      when [month]="MAY" then 5
      when [month]="JUN" then 6
      when [month]="JUL" then 7
      when [month]="AUG" then 8
      when [month]="SEP" then 9
      when [month]="OCT" then 10
      when [month]="NOV" then 11
      when [month]="DEC" then 12 end,
   1)
```

I would name it something like "monthdate". Note that each date will have the day equal to 1. If you also have the day in your data, just put that column in the formula above instead of the last `1`.